# Issue With Primefaces Theme Creation With OSNODE?

Tags: primefaces, themes, themeroller

Few day back i found a [post](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=2810) by Primefaces project lead and i am trying to create the jar file with the help of [link](https://themeroller.osnode.com/) given on that post but when i uploaded the zip file and click on the Create theme jar i got the exception please refer attached Screenshot.I created themes with the help of [ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/).
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Answer given by **OSNODE** Team

First of all it appears your zip file is a bit big: **1.8 MB**. If you follow the instructions on the information tab (unchecked all modules in **themeroller**) it should be closer to or less than **500 kb**.

Secondly, it appears the theme created is not a custom theme but that you have selected the "**ui-lightness**" theme. This theme is already available so there should be no need to recreate it.

If any of my assumptions are wrong - then please describe the procedure you are following in creating your zip on the **themeroller** site.